# requests.get(url).headers.get('content-disposition') returning NONE on PYTHON

Tags: python-3.x, url, python-requests

Well, I've got the need of automate a process in my job(actually I'm an intern), and I just wondered if I could use Python for such process. I'm still processing my ideas of how to do those stuffs, and now I'm currently trying to understand how to download a file from a web URL using python3. I've found a guide on another website, but there's no active help there. I was told to use the module `requests` to download the actual file, and the module `re` to get the real file name.

The code was working fine, but then I tried to add some features like GUI, and it just stopped working. I took off the GUI code, and it didn't work again. Now I have no idea of what to do to get the code working, pls someone helo me, thanks :)

code:

````
import os
import re
    
# i have no idea of how this function works, but it gets the real file name
def getFilename(cd):
    if not cd:
        print("check 1")
        return None
    fname = re.findall('filename=(.+)', cd)
    if len(fname) == 0:
        print("check 2")
        return None
    return fname[0]

def download(url):
    # get request
    response = requests.get(url)
    # get the real file name, cut off the quota and take the second element of the list(actual file name)
    filename = getFilename(response.headers.get('content-disposition'))
    print(filename)
    # open in binary mode and write to file
    #open(filename, "wb").write(response.content)

download("https://pixabay.com/get/57e9d14b4957a414f6da8c7dda353678153fd9e75b50704b_1280.png?attachment=")
os.system("pause")```
````

Comment: Are there any errors?   Are you sure the header is ```content-disposition```?

Comment: @ewong yeah i'm sure it's `content-disposition`.. I don't know if I can leave the website here, but there you go: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/downloading-files-from-web-using-python

I've just put the functions into a new function.

And there's no error, the function `download` is just returning NONE, as it enters on the first `if-statement`.

Comment: Check the url. It says invalid url when trying to open in browser.

Comment: @Tarique it does work for me on Chrome, and I've already tested other URLs.

Comment: I have no idea, but the command `requests.get(url)` is returning a response 400 (bad request), and when I try to use a github download link, I get the 403 (forbidden)...

Comment: I'm guessing it requires some sort of User-Agent header string set.

Comment: @ewong but it was working perfectly fine before... How do I use that User-Agent header? I've never worked with these functions, and I'm really newbie on this.